# How do I configure smuxi-server to run as a normal service?

Tags: upstart, services, irc

I installed the smuxi-engine package on my Ubuntu 14.04 server which contains the `smuxi-server` binary. But I do not see instructions anywhere on configuring it to run as a service.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create an upstart configuration file:

  `sudo nano /etc/init/smuxi-server.conf`

  ```
  start on runlevel [2345]
  stop on runlevel [016]

  exec /usr/bin/smuxi-server
  ```
- Now, `smuxi-server` will start on boot and you can control as any service (upstart job).

  ```
  sudo service smuxi-server [start|stop|restart|status]
  sudo [start|stop|restart|status] smuxi-server
  ```
- That was the minimum configuration, To learn about available options see [Upstart Intro, Cookbook and Best Practises](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/)

Comment: I have a pending edit, the stop on runlevel should be 016 not 06

Comment: @postfuturist, Thank you I didn't notice that.